# CMake. Create coverage target

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, code-coverage, target

Sorry for such popular question. But I can't correspondingly apply answers from here to my environment.

I have api and tests to it. Both are subprojects to main "dummy" project. I stuck because I used CMake-anitpattern:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
set(CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH FALSE)
add_subdirectory ( src )
add_subdirectory ( test )

add_custom_target(coverage
    COMMAND make
    COMMAND sh ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/do_coverage.sh
)
```

That `COMMAND make` is bad solution because I planning to build my project on Windows later (yep, I need put commands from sh-script in CMakeLists.txt for this purpose too).

So, how can I let CMake to build **test** project in automatic mode for doing coverage things (gcov, gcovr) even if after `cmake` I want to `make coverage` straightway?
Thanks!

Comment: I hope [this example](https://github.com/gergap/helloworld) can help you.

Comment: Thanks @Gluttton
Seems you used CTest in your project but in my case I have test sources with Google Test definitions.

My question is how to build gtest binary in automatic mode while coverage target is executing? Sorry if I like blindfolded person in front of your example.

Answer (score 0):

you may use `cmake` to build it like this:

```
add_custom_target(
    coverage
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMAND sh ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/do_coverage.sh
  )
```

Comment: Thanks. But ```add_dependencies(coverage libproject_test)``` fixed my problem. My mess was in putting subdirectory name to this command instead of name of subproject.